# How to delete selected rows in uitable?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-uitable

I'd like to delete selected rows of an uitable.
I thought about using a checkbox for every row to select which one I want to delete.

But I can not add a column to a table with checkbox Set to false.

I get this follow error

```
??? Conversion to cell from logical is not possible.

Error in ==> loadTable at 7
    data(:,5) = true;
```

I tried with this:

```
 function loadTable(hTable, arrayHeaderAndData, columnFormatAtt)

        header = arrayHeaderAndData{1};
        % Add column delete
        header = [header 'Del'];
        data = arrayHeaderAndData{2};
        data(:,5) = true;
        columnFormatCases = [columnFormatCases 'logical'];

        set(hTable, 'Data',data,...
            'visible','on',...
            'ColumnWidth','auto',...
            'ColumnName',header,...
            'ColumnEditable', [false false false false],...
            'ColumnFormat', columnFormatAtt
    );


    end
```

Then I need to delete all rows with selected checkboxes from table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for another column with checkbox, just to indicate which row you want to delete. I would rather use the `uipushtool` to add a delete button, which deletes all rows previously selected.

```
function myTable 

h = figure('Position',[600 400 402 100],'numbertitle','off','MenuBar','none');

defaultData = rand(5,2);
uitable(h,'Units','normalized','Position',[0 0 1 1],...
              'Data', defaultData,... 
              'Tag','myTable',...    
              'ColumnName', [],'RowName',[],...
              'CellSelectionCallback',@cellSelect);

% create pushbutton to delete selected rows
tb = uitoolbar(h);
uipushtool(tb,'ClickedCallback',@deleteRow);
end

function cellSelect(src,evt)
% get indices of selected rows and make them available for other callbacks
index = evt.Indices;
if any(index)             %loop necessary to surpress unimportant errors.
    rows = index(:,1);
    set(src,'UserData',rows);
end
end

function deleteRow(~,~)
th = findobj('Tag','myTable');
% get current data
data = get(th,'Data');
% get indices of selected rows
rows = get(th,'UserData');
% create mask containing rows to keep
mask = (1:size(data,1))';
mask(rows) = [];
% delete selected rows and re-write data
data = data(mask,:);
set(th,'Data',data);
end
```

Comment: When I execute this script I see correctly rows, but I don' see button or anything else for delete

Comment: because an icon is missing ;) the button is in the upper left corner of the additional menu bar, just invisible. You can add an Icon using the property `cdata` or you can also use any other type of button, was just an idea.

Comment: This function works fine, but I return to my original issue because the cells must be editable. That's why I wanted the cell to be editable only on double click, to enable the selection of just a single click for delete. I 've add to table : "'ColumnEditable', true,..."

Comment: come into this chat please: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/40621/matlab-uitable?tab=general

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to assign to a cell, rather than into a cell.

Here is what I would try:

```
data(:,5) = {true}
```

Or alternately:

```
[data{:,5}] = deal(true)
```

If you are still struggling read `help cell`.